# Using Express / request, how to stream a very large requested file without downloading on server side

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I have a 15GB video file that I would like to proxy through Node.js. This code works fine:

```
app.all('/shareRedirects/:path', cors({origin: '*'}), function (req, res) {
    var path = req.params.path;
    request.get(path).pipe(res);
});
```

The issue is that the entire file needs to download on server side before being sent to client via Express / request. What's the best way to break it into chunks?

Comment: I would have assumed that using `.pipe()` will tell `request` to stream the data instead of first downloading it. If you're sure that's not what it does, you probably have to look at another HTTP request package (like `needle`).

Answer (score 0):

after further investigation, it seems `.pipe()` does stream it in chunks.

[image]